# Setting state in componentDidMount with loops and ifs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, react-router

I have a provider that provides tags for news articles (list with news). If they are more than three, then the additional tags (>3) will be grouped together (called plusTags in the example code). I can see in my console that I have all the tags, but they are not distributed correctly. Ex.

On the first page I have four news with the distributed tags "a,b,c", b", "ac" "b". On the next page, the news articles are (obviously) different, but the distribution of the tags is the SAME ("a,b,c", b", "ac" "b") as on the first page, even if the tags should be different. So the distribution follows the same pattern. I suspect it's my code in my "componentDidMount" function, as its there where I distribute all the tags. Suspect it might repeat because this function repeats itself?

```
public componentDidMount(): void {
  let tags = [];
  let plusTags = [];

  if (this.props.tags != null) {
    if (this.props.tags.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (this.props.tags[i] != undefined) {
          tags.push(this.props.tags[i] + " ");
        }
      }

      for (var j = this.props.tags.length - 1; j >= 3; j--) {
        if (this.props.tags[i] != undefined) {
          plusTags.push(this.props.tags[j] + " ");
        }
      }
    } else {
      tags = this.props.tags;
    }
  }

  this.setState({
    tags: tags,
    plusTags: plusTags
  });
}
```

and in my render

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<INewsTagsProps> {
   return <React.Fragment>
     <div className={styles.tagContainer}>
    {
      this.state.tags ? 
      this.state.tags.map((t) => {
        if (this.props.background == BackgroundType.None) {
          return (
            <a href={this.props.tagPageUrl + "?tag="+ t}>
              <span className={styles.tagNewsTiles}>{t}</span>
            </a>);
        }
        else {
          return(
            <a href={this.props.tagPageUrl + "?tag="+ t}>
              <span className={styles.tagFollowedNews}>{t}</span>
          </a>);
        }
      })
      : null 
    }
    {this.state.plusTags.length > 0 ?  
      <span className={`callout-target-${this.state.targetIndex} ${this.props.background == BackgroundType.None ? styles.tagNewsTiles : styles.tagFollowedNews}`} 
      onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); this.setState({plusTagsDialogOpen: true});}}>+ {this.state.plusTags.length}</span>
      :
      null
    }
   </div>
   <Callout
          className="ms-CalloutExample-callout"
          gapSpace={0}
          target={this.state.target}
          onDismiss={() => this.closeDialog()}
          hidden={!this.state.plusTagsDialogOpen}
          isBeakVisible={true}
          beakWidth={10}              
          directionalHint={DirectionalHint.topCenter}
      >

  <div className={styles.tagPopupWrapper}>
     <div className={styles.tagPopupContainer}>
      {this.state.plusTags ? 
        this.state.plusTags.map((t) => {
        if (this.props.background == BackgroundType.None) {
          return (
            <a href={this.props.tagPageUrl+ "?tag="+t}>
              <span className={styles.tagNewsTiles}>{t}</span>
            </a>);
        }
        else {
          return(
            <a href={this.props.tagPageUrl+ "?tag="+t}>
              <span className={styles.tagFollowedNews}>{t}</span>
            </a>);
        }
      }):
      null}
      </div>
    </div>              
  </Callout>
```

;

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it will be difficult to help you. It might be that the props are given to your component later as a result of e.g. a network request, so the `tags` prop might not be set when your component is created and `componentDidMount` is called.

Comment: Assuming the component never unmounts - that function will not be recalled. If it has to recalculate the tags based on the page changing then it is probably best to do this in a seperate function and call it when you need it.

Comment: I have updated my code tih my render